# How do I change a cell value dependant on a drop-down event?

Tags: excel, vba

I have almost found the answer to this in previous post, but not quite.

The scenario is as follows.

Column A contains values, based on a drop down list.

When I change a value - on any row in column A - I want the current date to be written into to the corresponding row in column C. The date must not change when I save and re-open the file at a later point, i.e. the =TODAY() function won't do it.

The user might change a multiple values on different rows in column A before exiting and saving the file.

Thankful for any input.

Mårten.

Comment: [Use the worksheet change event.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should meet your needs, paste this vba code into the Microsoft Excel Object for the worksheet you desire (so if this is for Sheet1, paste it into Sheet1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim controlRng, nRng As Range
'This will be the entire range of drop downs you have, I've set it to be the entire column A, if that's not suitable then change it to a set range
Set controlRng = Range("A:A")
Set nRng = Intersect(controlRng, Target)

If nRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

If Target.Value <> "" Then
    Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = Now
End If

End Sub
```